# wstool user and password

Tags: ros, wstool

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use wstool on private git repos. But for some reasons (shared computer), I have to clone over HTTPS. It is quite annoying to type my username and password everytime I do `wstool up`. Is there anyway I can type it only once evertyime I want to update repos?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213280/wstool-user-and-password/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the ssh version of the git url in your rosinstall file, for example `https://github.com/wjwwood/serial.git` would become `git@github.com:wjwwood/serial.git`.  This will use your ssh keys. If you're on a shared computer and can't put your ssh keys on it (which is what you've described) then you can use git-credential cache to "save" your user name and password for a short time:

http://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache

`wstool` does not store your password or ask for it on principal to avoid any security concerns. You can also setup a `.netrc` file, but that's not generally a good idea, especially on a shared computer, since it stores your password in plain text.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4